# Getting NosuchElement exception when trying to click on element after switching to webview in Android automation

Tags: android, automation, appium

I am trying to switch to webview and after switching i am getting element not found exception for Android automation, even i tried to check for frames on web but there is no frame.

If someone can tell me what I am missing after switching to webview and not getting the element to click.

i tried with xpath, css but i am getting element not found. i am able to switch to webview but after that i am getting the element not found error. i tried the explicit wait as well still issue is same.
can some one tell me where i am missing or what capability i can use to resolve this.

```
              public void switchToWebView2() {
Set<String> contextNames = androidDriver.getContextHandles();
List<String> handlesList = new ArrayList(contextNames);
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
System.out.println("+" + contextName
    + "+"); // prints out something like NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1
                         }

System.out.println(androidDriver.getContext());
String webApp = handlesList.get(1);
androidDriver.context(webApp);
            }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.